# Business logic and services

Tags: java, architecture, service, business-logic, business-logic-layer

In a three-tier/multitier architecture (UI/Logic/DAO/Domain model), can services be considered as belonging to the business logic layer or are they situated as something separate ?

Comment: The word service in this case means a sort of stateless utility class that could contain mostly static methods but is usually rewritten so it can instantiable (in order to accomodate changes in requirements).

Ex: LoginService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably find that a fairly generic word like "service" means different things to different people.

I think of a service as something that orchestrates the logic exposed by business objects (or other services) to implement a useful task (such as a business process).  So, for me, a service is a consumer of the business logic layer (and probably of support aspects such as logging).